# OS 10.8 Preview URL Annotation

Tags: macos, preview.app

In the Preview app for Mac OSX Mountain Lion, I am missing the ability to add URL annotations. I have also downloaded Adobe Acrobat Reader, and found that this too now lacks this feature.

What free or cheap software could I buy that allows for URL annotations, or even better, how can I do URL annotations using Preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview no longer include url annotations, nor does it look like it will in the future.

However, PDFPen seems to be a good alternative. Found both as an app in the App Store, and also on their website [here.](http://smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/index.html) If you go the website, you can find a free trial which will last indefinitely, but stamp each pdf you edit with a Smile Software logo.